# How to plot/graph top modes through panda python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So i have a column in a CSV file that I would like to gather data on. It is full of integers, but I would like to bar-graph the top 5 "modes"/"most occurred" numbers within that column. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Better give sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a big list of integers in the form of a pandas series `s`.

`s.value_counts().plot.bar()` should do it.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.value_counts().head().plot(kind='bar')`

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,3,5,8,1,5,6,9,8,7,5,6,7],'b':[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,2]})

df
    a  b
0   1  1
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   5  3
5   8  3
6   1  4
7   5  5
8   6  6
9   9  7
10  8  7
11  7  7
12  5  7
13  6  8
14  7  2

df.b.value_counts().head() # count values of column 'b' and show only top 5 values
7    4
3    3
2    2
1    2
8    1
Name: b, dtype: int64


df.b.value_counts().head().plot(kind='bar') #create bar plot for top values
```

[image]